# Virtual Method Best Method? - C# Predator/Prey Sim

Tags: c#

Splitting this question up into multiple parts :)

My goal is to create a predator/prey simulation based on some code provided. Some of it I understand, some of it I do not. One of my goals is to modify the parent class SimObject and/or it's child classes Plants and Caterpillars to go from displaying "*" (inherited from SimObject) to displaying a unique character for each class ("^" for Plants, "-" for Caterpillars). I used a virtual/override method, but I'm not sure if there is a better way? Below is the code as I've modified it:

```
    public virtual void Draw() //Draw Method from Parent class SimObject
    {
        // Draw the character to the screen in the correct position
        Console.SetCursorPosition(Column, Row);
        Console.ForegroundColor = Color;    
        Console.Write("*");
    }

    public override void Draw()//Override default, inside class Plant:SimObject.
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(Column, Row);
        Console.ForegroundColor = Color;
        Console.Write("^");

    public override void Draw()//Override default Symbol, inside class Caterpillar:SimObject.
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(Column, Row);
        Console.ForegroundColor = Color;
        Console.Write("-");
```

Below this, if needed, is the full source code as given to me. It may help with provide better context.

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;

// ----------------------------------------------------------------
// Everything should be column, row
// ----------------------------------------------------------------
public class SimObject
{
    private int mRow, mColumn;
    public int Column
    {
        get { return mColumn; }
        set
        {
            if (value >= 0)
                mColumn = value;
            else
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Column cannot be negative");
        }
    }
    public int Row
    {
        get { return mRow; }
        set
        {
            if (value >= 0 && value < Console.WindowHeight)
                mRow = value;
            else
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Row cannot be negative");
        }
    }


    public SimObject(int aColumn, int aRow, ConsoleColor aColor = ConsoleColor.White)
    {
        Column = aColumn;
        Row = aRow;
        Color = aColor;
    }

    // Allow each child to have a unique color
    public ConsoleColor Color { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "SimObject at " + Column + ", " + Row;
    }

    public void Draw()
    {
        // Draw the character to the screen in the correct position
        Console.SetCursorPosition(Column, Row);
        Console.ForegroundColor = Color;    
        Console.Write("*"); // hard-coded the character - its the same for each child :(
    }

    public virtual void Turn(List <SimObject> theList)
    { }
}

public class Plant : SimObject
{
    private int mAmount;
    public int Amount
    {
        get { return mAmount; }
        set
        {
            if (value >= 0)
                mAmount = value;
            else
                mAmount = 0;//throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Amount of plant cannot be negative");
        }
    }

    public Plant(int aColumn, int aRow, int anAmount = 5)
        : base(aColumn, aRow, ConsoleColor.DarkGreen)   // Use DarkGreen for plants
    {
        Amount = anAmount;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Plant at " + Column + ", " + Row + " with amount = " + Amount;
    }

    public override void Turn(List<SimObject> theList)
    {
        // Add to the plant's amount every turn
        if (Amount != 0 && Amount < 5)
            Amount++;

        // Add a new plant to theList when amount > 12
    }

    public void Eat()
    {
        if (Amount > 0)
            Amount = Amount - 2;
    }
}

public class Caterpillar : SimObject
{
    private static Random aRan = new Random();

    public Caterpillar(int aColumn, int aRow, int aSpeed = 1)
        : base(aColumn, aRow, ConsoleColor.Red)
    {
        Speed = aSpeed;
    }

    private int mSpeed;
    public int Speed
    {
        get { return mSpeed; }
        set
        {
            if (value >= 0)
                mSpeed = value;
            else
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Speed of caterpillar cannot be negative");
        }
    }

    public override void Turn(List<SimObject> theList)
    {
        SimObject so = theList.Find(x => this != x && x.Row == Row && x.Column == Column);

        if (so is Plant)               // it's a plant, so don't move the caterpillar away from it
        {   
            Plant p = (Plant)so;
            if (p.Amount > 0)         // eat some of the plant if any is left
                p.Eat();
            else if (p.Amount == 0)   // if no plant is left, remove the plant from theList (this is the simulation's list)
                theList.Remove(p);
        }
        else //if (so == null)        // no other object in this space, so try moving to a new space without another caterpillar
        {
            // Move randomly but not off the screen's edges
            int newCol = Column + aRan.Next(-2, 3);
            int newRow = Row + aRan.Next(-2, 3);
            while (newCol < 0 || newCol >= Console.WindowWidth || newRow < 0 || newRow >= Console.WindowHeight)
            {
                newCol = Column + aRan.Next(-2, 3);
                newRow = Row + aRan.Next(-2,3);
            }

            // make sure the new space is empty or has a plant (e.g. don't move on top of another caterpillar)
            so = theList.Find(x => this != x && x.Row == newRow && x.Column == newCol && x.Color != Color);
            if (so == null || (so is Plant))
            {
                Column = newCol;
                Row = newRow;
            }
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Caterpillar at " + Row + ", " + Column + " with speed = " + Speed;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, this question is way too big.  Try breaking it down into smaller pieces and posting one (specific) question at a time.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot change the parent class, then yes, this seems to be the best way.

If you are allowed to change the parent class, you could make the character to print a property of the parent class and replace the hard-coded value so child classes only need to set it, like the Color.

Answer (score 0):

I am agree with @nvoigt answer .. if you could `change the base class` then . you can follow the below pattern ..

```
public class SimObject
{
    //.........Rest properties

    public virtual char DrawChar { get{return '*';}}

    public virtual void Draw() 
    {            
        //.....rest code
        Console.Write(DrawChar);
    }
}

public class Plant : SimObject
{
    //.........Rest properties
    public override char DrawChar { get { return '^'; } }

    public void SomeFunction()
    {
        base.Draw();//will print out '^' in end
    }
}

public class Caterpillar : SimObject
{
    //.........Rest properties
    public override char DrawChar { get { return '-'; } }

    public void SomeFunction()
    {
        base.Draw();//will print out '-' in end
    }
}

public class SomeOtherClass : SimObject
{
    //.........Rest properties       

    public void SomeFunction()
    {
        base.Draw();//will print out '*' in end
    }
}
```

Else what you have **done** so far is the best way to accomplish your task